# Hosting WCF service in Unit Test using ServiceHost

Tags: .net, asp.net, wcf, unit-testing, mstest

I am trying to write some unit tests that test the endpoints for my WCF service and to do this I want to host the service within the unit tests itself rather than in IIS.  I have found [this article](http://blog.clauskonrad.net/2008/12/wcf-unittesting.html) that I have read through and made the changes so I am hosting it using `ServiceHost` and I can see that the unit tests are trying to run it but I seem to be hitting a bit of a problem.

When I run the tests, I get the following error at the point of opening the service:

> This service requires ASP.NET
>   compatibility and must be hosted in
>   IIS.  Either host the service in IIS
>   with ASP.NET compatibility turned on
>   in web.config or set the
>   AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsAttribute.AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode
>   property to a value other than
>   Required.

This is being caused by the following attribute setting on my services class:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements( RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required )]
```

I have then tried to add the following into my app.config but it doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
<system.serviceModel>
  <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" />
</system.serviceModel>
```

Any ideas how I can get past this issue?

Comment: That's easy to fix: just remove the ASP.NET compatibility requirement. No, seriously: you should.

Comment: In the end I did that, just removed the attribute.  I was concerned that I didn't know the exact reason for it being there in the first place but I suppose thats why we have unit tests, CI and nightly builds!!! :)

Comment: You would need it back when you start missing the `HttpContext` ;) Then of course self-hosting goes out of the window!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As stated by the error message, **the ASP.NET compatibility mode requires the WCF service to be hosted in an ASP.NET web server**.

If you wish to run some integration tests against your WCF service on your local machine you can always **host the service in the Visual Studio Development Server** (a.k.a. *Cassini*). I highly recommend you to take a look at [CassiniDev](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/), an open source library that allows to **run a lightweight ASP.NET web server in process**, which is especially useful for unit testing scenarios.

Here's an example of how you would use CassiniDev in a unit test using MSTest:

```
[TestClass]
public class MyServiceTest
{
    private CassiniDevServer host;

    [TestInitialize]
    public void SetUp()
    {
        var host = new CassiniDevServer();
        host.StartServer(@"RelativePathToServiceProjectDir", 8080, "/", "localhost");
    }

    [TestCleanup]
    public void TearDown()
    {
       host.StopServer();
    }
}
```

**Related resources:**

- [CassiniDev Documentation](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/documentation)
- [Using CassiniDev with unit testing frameworks and continuous integration](http://cassinidev.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Using%20CassiniDev%20with%20unit%20testing%20frameworks%20and%20continuous%20integration&referringTitle=Documentation)

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to CassiniDev, its pretty cool!!  I tried to integrate it and it ran perfectly when running on my machine but I had issues getting it running under TeamCity for the CI build...so I ended opting for removing the attribute.

Comment: How would you go about changing the web.config of the project under test to point to test database and stuff?